# Casting required for variable assignment?

Tags: java

I am new to Android. One thing slowing coding down tremendously is the errors generated by a statement like:

```
String logoPath = infoMap.get("LogoPath");
```

which seems to require an explicit cast to String in order to be accepted e.g.

```
String logoPath = (String)infoMap.get("LogoPath");
```

Can this explicit cast requirement be turned off? I am already telling the compiler to expect a string...

Comment: This is related to any other language which has types such as C, C++, C#, etc.

Comment: @FatalError It's usually helpful to give a hint as to which code would help. (In this case starting with the type of `infoMap` and if it's a custom type, the signature of `get()` and maybe its implementation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this explicit cast requirement be turned off?

Only if you can change the expression `infoMap.get("LogoPath")` to be of type `String`. We don't know what `infoMap` is at the moment, but *if* you can declare it as `Map<String, String>` then it should just work. Perhaps you're using a raw `Map` type at the moment?

If you can't change `infoMap.get(...)` to return `String`, then the cast is absolutely required. You're basically saying to the compiler, "I know you can't check this, but I'm sure that the value returned by this method is a string reference (or null). Please check at execution time instead." It also serves as a warning to anyone *reading* the code that there's a theoretical (at least) possibility of it going wrong.

Casts indicate a situation where the type system isn't working as effectively as you'd like it to - you'd *like* to be able to verify at compile-time that the `get` method returns a `String`-compatible reference. See what you can do to make that the case - and if you can't, you're stuck with the cast.